# POST from REST console perceived as GET by server

Tags: symfony, nginx

Im using both the chrome REST API console and Postman to send a post request to my server (running nginx and symfony2)

Its a very simple request, just simply posting to a URL with an empty body. If this request runs from another server via a HTTP request, it will register as POST. Trying to POST from the api consoles registers as GET in my nginx access logs and returns a 405 Method not allowed.

If I use curl I initially get a 301 Moved Permanently, so I have to use -L to follow redirects. Im not sure if this is standard Symfony or if it is effecting the request.

I've found some problems with the curl request, but am unsure how to resolve them.

```
$ curl -v -L -d "1EepG1a63X" xxx.io/api/convert_mov/
*   Trying xx.76.9.82...
* Connected to xxx.io (xx.76.9.82) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/convert_mov/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: xxx.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 10
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 10 out of 10 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 09:00:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 184
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://xxx.io/api/convert_mov/
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host xxx.io left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://xxx.io/api/convert_mov/'
* Switch from POST to GET
* Found bundle for host xxx.io: 0x7fcad9c14e70
*   Trying xx.76.9.82...
* Connected to xxx.io (xx.76.9.82) port 443 (#1)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: xxx.io
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert Global Root CA
> GET /api/convert_mov/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: xxx.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.25
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 09:00:43 GMT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closer, you will see your request is with HTTP. Then your server sends a redirect to your HTTPS site. And a 301 redirect does not preserve the request method. You MUST issue all your requests correctly against HTTPS.

Comment: Interesting, I thought, at least as for protocol, that original `method` would be preserved. Useful info...

Comment: Haha, IE does make our lives a lot more fun :D